# Eclipse Does Not Download All Plugins From A p2 Repository

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have been given an RCP application to build in eclipse. I was also provided with a list of p2 repository locations (on Nexus repo manager). When I try to build a target platform (or install the repos as new software in Eclipse) I notice that the Eclipse does not fetch all the plugins in a p2 repo.

I can visit the p2 repo site. I can see the repo structure with the **content.xml/jar** and **artifacts.xml/jar**, with **plugins** and **features** folders

The structure of the repo:
[image: The structure of the repo]

There are a lot of plugins in the **plugins** folder but when this site is installed as a new software in Eclipse (or added to a target platform) there are just a few of them downloaded.

I can find the reference to missing plugins in the artifact.xml and content.xml (and I cannot see any difference between those that have been fetched)

What could be wrong?

Comment: Adding knowledge of a repository location isn't the same thing as *installing* everything from there. Your Target Platform file has to actually list the features and/or plug-ins you wanted to pull from each location.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought that adding a site to target platform in eclipse (and selecting everything available on that site in the "Add Software Site" wizard) would pull everything. Could you please explain how can I tell eclipse to pull every available plugin/feature?

Comment: Where in the UI are you doing this "selecting of everything available on that site"?

Comment: When you edit the target platform in eclipse (Window/Preferences/Plug-in Dev./Target Platform) you can add software site as a resource. The "Add Software Site" popup allows you to add a software site. When loaded there are "items" listed that you can check out to fetch as a part of the resource. The problem is that these items do not correspond to the plugins or features on this site but are some kind of groupings (even with Group by Category unchecked). Even when selecting everything eclipse can "find" on the site the vast majority of the plugins that are actually in the repo are not fetched.